# How to replace operator new/delete and not interfere with libraries?

Tags: c++, linux

Let's say I want to add some meta information to allocated objects to track allocations/deallocations.
I learned that it's enough to replace one version of [operator new](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new) and two versions of [operator delete](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_delete) to handle all allocations since C++11.

Here's what I've written:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <FreeImage.h>

#include <new>
#include <iostream>

void *operator new(size_t size)
{
    std::cout << "allocation of size " << size << '\n';
    void *allocated = malloc(size + sizeof(size_t));
    *reinterpret_cast<size_t *>(allocated) = size;
    return reinterpret_cast<void *>(reinterpret_cast<size_t *>(allocated) + 1);
}

void _delete(void *ptr) {
    void *allocated = reinterpret_cast<void *>(reinterpret_cast<size_t *>(ptr) - 1);
    size_t size = *reinterpret_cast<size_t *>(allocated);
    std::cout << "deallocation of size " << size << '\n';
    free(allocated);
}

void operator delete(void *ptr) noexcept
{
    _delete(ptr);
}

void operator delete(void *ptr, std::align_val_t al) noexcept
{
    _delete(ptr);
}

int main()
{
    auto str = new char[1337];
    delete str;
    FreeImage_Initialise();
}

// compiled with `g++ -std=c++17 reproduce.cpp -lfreeimage`
```

This program works if I don't use any third-party functions, but fails if I do.

The program crash with `free(): invalid pointer` and gdb says it fails inside of _delete which, I guess, means that something was allocated with standard allocator, but was freed with my own.

GDB output:

```
(gdb) bt
#0  __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:50
#1  0x00007ffff79a9535 in __GI_abort () at abort.c:79
#2  0x00007ffff7a10516 in __libc_message (action=action@entry=do_abort, fmt=fmt@entry=0x7ffff7b34c00 "%s\n") at ../sysdeps/posix/libc_fatal.c:181
#3  0x00007ffff7a173aa in malloc_printerr (str=str@entry=0x7ffff7b32d85 "free(): invalid pointer") at malloc.c:5336
#4  0x00007ffff7a191fc in _int_free (av=<optimized out>, p=<optimized out>, have_lock=<optimized out>) at malloc.c:4143
#5  0x00005555555552e8 in _delete(void*) ()
#6  0x0000555555555303 in operator delete(void*) ()
#7  0x00007ffff7d7edc2 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreeimage.so.3
#8  0x00007ffff79cba77 in __cxa_finalize (d=0x7ffff7fa0000) at cxa_finalize.c:83
#9  0x00007ffff7d17003 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreeimage.so.3
#10 0x00007fffffffdec0 in ?? ()
#11 0x00007ffff7fe3d16 in _dl_fini () at dl-fini.c:138
```

So the question: How to replace new/delete properly?

Comment: All identifiers that begin with an underscore in the global namespace are reserved and can't be used. `_delete` violates that. It might not be the cause of your problem but it would be best to fix it and eliminate it as a possible cause. Edit : You can find a list of restricted identifiers [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/identifiers).

Comment: SUGGESTION: print out the addresses returned by malloc() and passed to free(), to verify they're correct.  And I agree: "_delete()" is an unwise choice of names :(

Comment: `objcopy` the library and substitute standard names for new and delete for new ones. Provide them in your translation unit. Overwrite the defaults in another. Link. There is no other option - you need to substitute the function names in the library code.

Comment: Strictly speaking you should be using placement `new` to write the size into the extra allocated memory.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out `_delete`, but even if I rename it to something like `my_delete` it behaves the same.

Comment: @KamilCuk I don't mind if other libs use my new/delete. I just want them to not crash :)

Comment: One more suggestion (for troubleshooting): add a private member,`addr`, to your class.  Save it at "malloc()"; compare it at "free()".

Comment: Small suggestions, but `new` is expected to `throw std::bad_alloc` if it fails to allocate, so you should check that `malloc` succeeded. Second is that your cast chains can more cleanly be written `static_cast<size_t *>(allocated) + 1` and `static_cast<size_t *>(allocated) - 1`. A `static_cast` is sufficient and casting to `void*` can be done implicitly. As to what might be causing the problem, if `sizeof(size_t)` doesn't have the same alignment restriction as the most restricted scalar type, shifting the result of `malloc` by it may be misaligning your memory. Try placing it at the end.

Comment: There are many [`new`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new) and [`delete`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_delete) operators. You've overloaded `delete(void *, std::align_val_t)` but not the matching `new`. Perhaps that's the cause of the problem?

Comment: Things have changed since c++17, add also extended alignment allocation function. Also consider that gcc implementation of operator new call aligned_alloc

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I can't place it at the end because I need to get it when I'm deleting a pointer and I don't know the size of the allocated memory of a random pointer to find its end.

Also it seems I don't understand how alignment works. This may be the problem. I'll try to search some info about it.

Comment: @YegorTyuvaev That's a good point. Look at [`std::max_align_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/max_align_t). `alignof(std::max_align_t)` is guaranteed to be at least as strict as the largest alignment requirement of every scalar types. So if your `size` storage takes up a multiple of that alignment requirement you are okay. Though this might not even be the source of the problem. I'd check that the missing `new` overload isn't the cause. Seems like every overloaded `delete` needs a matched overloaded `new` (I think).

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer for my case.

I replaced these forms to have it working:

```
void *operator new(size_t size);

void *operator new(size_t size, std::align_val_t al);

void *operator new(size_t size, const std::nothrow_t &tag);

void *operator new(std::size_t size, std::align_val_t al, const std::nothrow_t &);

void operator delete(void *ptr);
```

Though I didn't replace aligned delete operator, the program stopped crashing.
But I guess it's still a good idea to replace aligned delete as well as cppreference.com suggests.

Comment: In other words, the problem was that there were some overloads you didn't anticipate, correct?  Please feel free to "accept" your answer.

Comment: @paulsm4 yes, I think this is the problem. I trusted too much to cppreference.com.
Or maybe the problem was that this rule of thumb from that website applies only to C++17 apps and the library might be built with older C++ standard. I don't want to dig deeper though.